# Js Jquery event repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code for my slider:

```
$('#left-product-slide').click(function(event){
var winwidth = $(window).width();
var left = $('.line-product').position();//Вычисляем позицию слайдера
var position = left.left+parseInt('-'+productwidth,10);//Вычисляем сдвиг по линии
if(position <= '-'+linewidth){
    $('.line-product').css('left',0);
}else{
    $('.line-product').css('left',position+'px');
}
});
```

All working good. But, when I click on the button quickly, several times my slides elements are shifted,although they should not. I think this is happening, because i clicked fast, and function started, so of this left position distorted. 
My question is :how can I not run the function again if it is not finished yet?

Comment: did you try ``event.preventDefault();``?

Comment: @Donald Wu  yes, i tried

Comment: @Donald Wu, my fail, all warking, Apply the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a test value to check if the slide still going

```
var isSliding = false;
$('#left-product-slide').click(function(event){
  if (isSliding)
    return;
  else {
    isSliding = true;
    var winwidth = $(window).width();
    var left = $('.line-product').position();//Вычисляем позицию слайдера
    var position = left.left+parseInt('-'+productwidth,10);//Вычисляем сдвиг по линии
    if(position <= '-'+linewidth){
      $('.line-product').css('left',0);
    }else{
      $('.line-product').css('left',position+'px');
    }
    isSliding = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.one()` method.

```
    $( "#left-product-slide" ).one( "click", function() {
      var winwidth = $(window).width();
      var left = $('.line-product').position();
      var position = left.left+parseInt('-'+productwidth,10);
      if(position <= '-'+linewidth){
        $('.line-product').css('left',0);
      }else{
        $('.line-product').css('left',position+'px');
     }
   });
```